# How to parse json array in postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I am trying to parse out the language for different profiles that are stored in a json field named "data". They are stored in their own array in the json field like:

```
"languages": ["EN", "BN", "HI"]
```

I can call the whole array by using:

```
data->>'languages' as languages
```

but I would like to split it out into

```
language1 = "EN"
language2 = "BN"
language3 = "HI"
```

I think if possible the best solution would be to return the whole language array but exclude "EN" from it, but I'm not sure if that is possible. ex.

```
"languages": ["BN", "HI"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-` operator to remove the `EN` key:

```
select (data -> 'languages') - 'EN' as languages
from the_table;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f23c35a1bfb01657030b662a5602b30e)

Comment: I get the logic you are using but I am getting an error message: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Do I need to change the data types?

Comment: @tidy2021: maybe `data` isn't defined as `jsonb` (or at least `json`)